# 66 mustang automatic (3 speed) adding fluid after removing pan gasket

Tags: ford, automatic-transmission, mustang, transmission-fluid, torque-converter

What I've done so far to the trans:
removed pan 
replaced filter
replaced pan gasket
put it back together

Issues:

1. I have a bad torque converter (lurches then stalls when selecting gear)
   no idea if i should drain the TC and refill
2. How much Trans fluid should I add back in? I've already added 2 quarts back. the dipstick reads far over filled (because it's cold)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Have you ran the transmission through the gears after adding tranny fluid?